# How to add VS Code snippet inside a template

Tags: ionic-framework, vscode-extensions, vuejs3, vscode-snippets, ionic-vue

I am trying to create ionic vue snippets. So far it seems to only work when added on the top level and not working when added inside a `template` or `div` tag. How can I insert snippets inside these tags?

**Snippet**

```js
  "ionic-vue Item": {
    "prefix": "ivitem",
    "body": [
      "<ion-item>",
        "<ion-label>",
          "${1:Item}",
        "</ion-label>",
      "</ion-item>"
    ],
    "description": "Creates ionc-vue item"
  },
```

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@modus/ionic-vetur , Also install `Vetur` before this package

Comment: Thanks @NajamUsSaqib though this does not quite solve the problem but I picked up a few things from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [snippet scope](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-scope) to `html,vue-html`:

```js
{
  "ionic-vue Item": {
    "scope": "html,vue-html",
    //...
  }
}
```